# Why can FM be demodulated non-coherently while PM cannot be demodulated non-coherently?

Tags: rf, frequency-modulation, detection, demodulation, digital-modulation

I have read that frequency modulation has the advantage that it can be demodulated non-coherently while phase modulation can only be demodulated coherently.

I don't find any reason to support this statement.

If the frequency variation of a cosinusoid carrier can be found, why can't its phase as a function of time be obtained?

Comment: Your question title asks why FM can't be demodulated non-coherently, in the question body text you assert that it has the advantage that it can. So what is your question?

Comment: Sorry , I have edited it

Comment: "*why can't its phase as function of time be obtained.*". Phase of a signal has meaning only when compared to a reference signal. In the case of a receiver, the received signal has to be compared to a reference signal generated by the local oscillator. Hence coherent detection.

Comment: Another way of looking at it : phase is the integral of frequency. Integration always involves finding some reference point to define the constant term (because the derivative of a constant is 0). Coherent detection provides that reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phase of a signal is only defined with respect to a reference. If the reference cannot be communicated, then the phase is meaningless.

Often when phase modulation is used, it's treated as Differential Phase Modulation. It's not the absolute phase of any symbol that's relevant, it's the change of phase since the last symbol.

Of course, as the symbol rate is usually constant and known, a defined change of phase in a defined time is the same as a frequency shift away from nominal for a defined time, and you see that the real difference between phase modulation and frequency modulation is what you call it, and how you interpret it.

Another way to handle phase modulation is to send a reference phase as a pilot symbol at some point in the burst, and then measure the phase of all symbols with respect to that reference.

Often a receiver will lock a local oscillator to the average phase of the pilot symbols in the transmission, and hey presto, you have a local reference with which you can coherently demodulate the remaining symbols.

So now what's the difference between phase demodulation as the difference between pilot and symbol, using a PLL to filter the pilot phases for better noise, and using a PLL to generate a coherent local reference from the pilots?

Comment: If I use general Analog  phase modulation and try to demodulate  it using non coherent demodulator I can't  be sure about message's DC value but rest of the things can be found, isn't it.

Comment: To add to a messages DC value is lost when we do it's Analog Frequency modulation, so both the scenarios are similar right ?

Comment: @SUNITAGUPTA "non-coherent" simply means "there's no phase relationship"; so, I don't really understand why you're even arguing here. "Why can't I receive the phase with something that I call 'not preserving the phase'" is not a very clever question!

Comment: @Marcus Müller I am sorry if it felt like arguing but just humbly asking(need to improve on my  conversation skills).

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sir a doubt here if I can demodulate frequency of a carrier wave can't I integrate it to  get phase and the  remove the DC value using a capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

FM can be demodulated for ex. with a filter which converts frequency variations to amplitude variations. Add a rectifier (=crystal detector) and the demodulator is ready. And it's non-coherent because it's not based on mixing with the carrier.

Phase modulation can be seen also as FM as you can see if you know the math formulas of FM and PM and understand the fact that frequency difference can be seen as phase angle changing rate. 1Hz frequency difference causes 360 degrees phase shift per second.

Thus phase modulation can detected with FM demodulator and that can be non-coherent. In practice the result would be non-satisfactory due poor frequency response.

Comment: I don't agree – you can demodulate *differential* phase modulation, but not phase modulation in general.

Comment: The DC component of the signal is ambiquous also with proper coherent phase modulation demodulator if special sync sessions do not happen.

Comment: exactly, but that's a separate issue – a *non-differential* phase modulation cannot be demodulated without absolute phase knowledge (i.e. phase sync). The uncertainty in DC comes from two things: 1. technical problems (LO leakage/suppression/DC offset) and 2. unknown phase (if you're demodulating with a cosine, but your carrier is a sine at the receiver, you get 0; if it is in-phase with the LO, then you get full amplitude). Correcting that makes your receiver coherent.

Comment: I have worked with circuits which have I and Q channels. There's no zero output amplitude problem.